# sprintf prepends extra character

Tags: c

I decided to write a binary converter, the code is small and simple , it takes an integer and is supposed to output a char* with the resulting binary string.

The issue here seems to be that the last sprintf always seems to double the  last prepended character.

For example if the answer is meant to be 1001001 it will print 11001001 or if it is supposed to be -10 it prints --10, the latter being particularly peculiar as that one isn't even in a loop.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void bin_string( char** buffer ,int num ){

    bool neg = false;

    if ( num < 0 ){
        neg = true;
        num = ~num+1;
    }

    if( num == 0 )
        sprintf( *buffer, "%d", 0 );

    while( num > 0 ){

        int rem = num%2;

        sprintf( *buffer, "%d%s", rem, *buffer );

        printf("iteration: %s rem: %d\n", *buffer, rem );
        num = num/2;
    }

    if( neg )
        sprintf( *buffer, "-%s", *buffer );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    char* a = malloc( sizeof(char)*64 );
    bin_string( &a, 73 );

    printf("Result %s\n",a ); /* output is 11001001 but should be 1001001*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why pass `char **buffer` to `bin_string()` if it doesn't allocate or otherwise change the pointer.  It would be simpler to pass `char *buffer` and use `buffer` instead of `*buffer`.  However, that's tangential to the problem you mention.

Comment: Did you step through in a debugger?

Comment: Side note - `num = -num;` is much more understandable than `num = ~num+1;` for most people.

Comment: I don't like the fact you're printing buffer into itself. This actually might be the reason. Try copying buffer to some other spot, then using it sprintf.

Comment: While we're suggesting refactoring, the body of `bin_string` could be written in the form `bool neg = (num < 0); num = neg ? -num : num; while (num > 0) {...} /* now place the negative sign if neg */ ...`. The character array could be written character by character starting from just before a terminating null at the end of the buffer and proceeding backward toward the start of the buffer, without any `sprintf` at all. Then `bin_string` could return the `char *` that points to the beginning of the resulting string within the buffer. On the other hand none of this was part of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration of [`sprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html) in C99 and beyond is:

```
    int sprintf(char *restrict s, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

You are violating the `restrict` part of that declaration.  You are using, for example:

```
sprintf(*buffer, "-%s", *buffer);
```

This is trying to modify the buffer in situ, and is undefined behaviour.  You're lucky you're getting such nearly sane results — or maybe unlucky.  You can't use the target buffer in the trailing arguments to the call to `sprintf()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer turns out you were completely right , copying buf to a temp variable solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose sprintf is just not smart enough to insert buffer into itself.  You probably need to have two buffers and swap them.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you're invoking **undefined behavior** when you're `sprintf()`ing `*buffer` to itself. What you should do instead is something like:

```
void bit_string(char *buf, int n)
{
    int nbits = sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nbits; i++) {
        buf[i] = '0' + ((n >> (nbits - i - 1)) & 1);
    }
    buf[nbits] = 0;
}
```

(Yes, I've also taken care of efficiency, readability and portability for you - you're welcome.)

Comment: This answer is algorithmically beautiful in simplicity, its probably more real world worthy too as we should expect a fixed size. My question was more focused on why my solution was not working rather than to obtain a better algorithm, but this was nice to see. I was given a bit shifting answer elsewhere which was roughly 1e6 lines long( slight hyperbole ). Nice to see that some still strive for the simple.

Comment: @CoDragon Thanks :) Experience and lazyness, that's all ;-)